# Writing a script to do repetitive business tasks inside a program

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have the following class that holds the start and end values ​​of a task

```
public class WorkPackage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToTime { get; set; }
}
```

I also show the saved values ​​as follows(grouped base on `FromTime`)

[image]

End user can

1. Move one `WorkPackage` from a month to another month by Drag & Drop.
2. Split one `WorkPackage` to two or more `WorkPackage`s base on some rules.

So I have following methods:

```
public void MoveWorkPackageToMonth(WorkPackage wp, int month)
{
   ....
} 
public List<WorkPackage> SplitWorkPackage(WorkPackage wp)
{
   ....
}
```

Each time the user makes a lot of changes to the `WorkPackage` list, but the `WorkPackage` list may be rebuilt every few days for business reasons, and user want to do same things on the re-created `WorkPackage` list, so I need to save the user's works in the database to repeat the same works on the re-created `WorkPackage` list.

I want to add something like a scripting language to save user works as a string, something like this:

```
"Move(WP1){From(January) To(April)};SPLIT(WP5);"
```

Is there any library to help me? or I have to define my own custom business language?(I used `.Net4`)

Comment: Is the script shown to the user? If not, a simple solution might be to create a data class for the action (e.g. `class PackageMovement { int PackageId; int SourceMonth; int DestMonth; } class PackageSplit { int PackageId; }` and serialize it using one of the built-in serializers (XML or JSON).

Comment: @Heinzi: user wants to see the script, because he want to select which actions to do

Comment: I see. In that case, a custom language would probably be the most comfortable solution. Since the language is fairly simple, I don't think you need a full-blown lexer/paser generator. A simple regex-based, hand-written parser should suffice: Write a regex for each of your commands (i.e., a MoveRegex and a SplitRegex), which includes the parameters as named groups. Then split your input on `;` or newline and try each regex in turn.

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet Package ITVComponents.Scripting.CScript provides a scripting engine that supports interpretet as well as compiled code.
The Syntax is derived from JavaScript with some special extensions to enable dynamic type loading and native script parts.
Unfortunately there is no documentation at the moment, but i'm working on it..

Basically, for what you want to achive, you could use the following code:

```
ExpressionParser.ParseBlock(yourScript, yourObject, s => DefaultCallbacks.PrepareDefaultCallbacks(s.Scope, s.ReplSession));
```

where yourObject would be the objects that implement the methods MoveWorkPackageToMonth,
SplitWorkPackage, a method to find a Package (FindPackage?) and the months als integer Properties and your script would look something like

`MoveWorkPackageToMonth(FindPackage("nameOfPackage1"), April); MoveWorkPackageToMonth(FindPackage("nameOfPackage2"), February); ...`

this code will work interpreted, therefore, if you have plenty of actions to perform, it may be slow.